# How to enable activemq plugin

Tags: java, plugins, activemq-classic, interceptor

I'm trying to create an interceptor for activemq (5.15.13).
I use code from https://activemq.apache.org/interceptors and compile it as jar file.
I added jar file to /lib folder.

Then I added to activemq.xml

```xml
<plugins>
            <loggingBrokerPlugin logAll="true" logConnectionEvents="true"/>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" id="myPlugin" class="com.xxx.mqplugin.MyPlugin"/>
</plugins>
```

I see

> jvm 1    |  INFO | Created LoggingBrokerPlugin: LoggingBrokerPlugin(logAll=true, logConnectionEvents=true, logSessionEvents=true, logConsumerEvents=false, logProducerEvents=false, logTransactionEvents=false, logInternalEvents=false)

But nothing about my plugin..
How to register and enable my plugin?

```java
package com.xxx.mqplugin;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.apache.activemq.broker.Broker;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.ConnectionContext;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.region.MessageReference;
import org.apache.activemq.command.ConnectionInfo;
import org.apache.activemq.command.ProducerInfo;
import org.apache.activemq.command.SessionInfo;

public class MyBroker extends BrokerFilter {

    public MyBroker(Broker next) {
        super(next);
    }

    public void addConnection(ConnectionContext context, ConnectionInfo info) throws Exception {

        // Your code goes here
        System.out.println("addConnection:" + info.toString());
        Logger.getLogger("test").info("addConnection:" + info.toString());

        // Then call your parent
        super.addConnection(context, info);
    }

    public void addSession(ConnectionContext context, SessionInfo info) throws Exception {

        // Your code goes here...
        System.out.println("addSession:" + info.toString());
        Logger.getLogger("test").info("addSession:" + info.toString());

        // Then call your parent
        super.addSession(context, info);
    }

    @Override
    public void addProducer(ConnectionContext context, ProducerInfo info) throws Exception {
        // Your code goes here...
        System.out.println("addProducer:" + info.toString());
        Logger.getLogger("test").info("addProducer:" + info.toString());

        super.addProducer(context, info);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void messageDelivered(ConnectionContext context,MessageReference messageReference) {
        
        
        System.out.println("messageDelivered:" + messageReference.toString());
        Logger.getLogger("test").info("messageDelivered:" + messageReference.toString());

        super.messageDelivered(context, messageReference);
    }
}

Thanks
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a "BrokerPlugin" object as well which is the type that is used to install your "BrokerFilter" instance.

```
import org.apache.activemq.broker.Broker;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerPlugin;

public class MyPlugin implements BrokerPlugin { 
        
        public Broker installPlugin(Broker broker) throws Exception {            
             return new MyBroker(broker);
        }   

}
```

That would then be the type you use in the broker XML configuration

```
  <plugins>
      <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" id="myPlugin" class="org.myorg.MyPlugin"/>    
  </plugins>
```

Comment: Yes I did it, but I don't see any message like for loggingBrokerPlugin that say that the plugin has been installed at activemq startup. (jvm 1    |  INFO | Created LoggingBrokerPlugin: LoggingBrokerPlugin....)

Comment: Does I have to just put my jar (mq-plugin-5.15.13.jar) in apache-activemq-5.15.13\lib\?